# Set Form.values to a foreign Site without ID / Access to sourcecode

Tags: javascript, php, forms, transfer, cross-site

**Short Process description:** The User put all required information into our website ( php / mysql / js enabled). With pushing "Enter" all information should be spread/shared to all relevant counter parts.

**My Idea**
Therefore I'd like to pass the information "Username, Email. Realname" to a "foreign" Mantis website (manage_user_create_page.php) where I do not have the possibility to change the code. The Target looks like:

```
<div align="center">
<table class="width50"><tr>
<form method="post" action="manage_user_create.php">
...
...
   <input type="text" name="username" size="32" maxlength="32" />
...
   <input type="text" name="realname" size="32" maxlength="64" />
...
   <input type="text" name="email" size="32" maxlength="64" />
...
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Create User" />
...
...
</tr></table></form></div>
```

I already tried to open it like: http://..../manage_user_create.php?username=Whatever

Is there any solution to put this Information, from my site into their one (more or less automatically) and maybe Submit() it, too? getElementById() wouldn't work, because of missing "id"...

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to make a HTTP-request to the other host of course. So in your case the form action have to be something like: http://[some_other_host]/manage_user_create.php

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. I just put the dots to simplify the url. In fact it is something like `http://mantis.domain.from.the.other.company/manage_user_create.php?username=v9000308`

Was your comment mention this?

Comment: So in your case in your `<form>` the `action`-attribute needs to be something like `http://mantis.domain.from.the.other.company/manage_user_create.php`. Then when you submit the form a HTTP `POST` (since your form has `method="post"`) request will be made to the webserver at `mantis.domain.from.the.other.company`

Comment: Which results into "building up a new site" with posting those variables to `mantis.../manage...php`, because I don't have the rights to change the code, right?

Comment: Well if the `manage_user_create.php`-script doesn't exists on the other server or that script doesn't accept the `POST` parameters you post and you don't have access to the server so you can change the script, then there isn't whole lot you can do...